# OpenGL--tiled map stretching when rotating except for at 0 degrees and 180 degrees

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics

I have a map consisting of 128x128 image tiles pieced together side-by-side. Our wizard stands at a location, and the map rotates according to the direction in which the wizard faces, the ideal function of which is illustrated by the following garbage MS Paint diagrams (please note: the NEWS directional labellings are not actually part of the map):

#### Facing North (Ideal AND Actual)

[image: Facing North (Ideal AND Actual)]

#### Facing East (Ideal, NOT Actual)

[image: Facing East (Ideal NOT Actual)]

However, though it works properly with the wizard facing true north and true south, the map is "stretched" and distorted at other angles of rotation, with the problem being the most apparent when the wizard faces true east or true west:

#### Facing East (Actual, NOT Ideal)

[image: Facing East (Actual NOT Ideal)]

Pseudocode of relevant code is as follows:

```
   glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
   glPushMatrix();
   glLoadIdentity();
   glOrtho(leftPosition,rightPosition,botPosition,topPosition,-1,1);
   glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
   glPushMatrix();
   glLoadIdentity();
   glRotatef(direction,0,0,1);
   glTranslatef(eastwestoffset,northsouthoffset,0);
   mapTiles();
   glTranslatef(-eastwestoffset,-northsouthoffset,0);
   glPopMatrix();
   glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
   glPopMatrix();
   glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
```

Does anything with the code jump out to anyone as the cause of the map working properly when facing north and south but stretching when facing other directions?

Comment: Maybe you calculated left/right/bot/topPosition wrong?

Comment: @immibis I suppose it's possible, but it seems to me (with my quite limited knowledge of OpenGL, mind you) that positional miscalculations wouldn't cause the map to stretch only when not rotated at 0 degrees or 180 degrees. I would think it would still looked skewed at those angles if positioning was the problem.

Comment: The values of the positional variables change based on where the wizard is currently located. There are also different "zoom" levels on the map that show varying ranges. -leftPosition = rightPosition and -botPosition = topPosition. Where I am right now, for example, leftPosition=-324, rightPosition=324, botPosition=-247, and topPosition=247.

Comment: Do you change the left/right/bot/topPosition when the screen rotates? If so, then that's why.